# Conditionally create ajax url parameter to use with jQuery Validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have an issue with my jquery validate script. Essentially, what I need is: based on what is in the last portion of a string (isAdd), when the user clicks the send button, the script will choose between the if or else statement and send an ajax request to validate an input field. The server will send an true or false flag. If true, the form will submit, if false, the form will not be submitted. I think my code shows it better:

```
// Waiting for the btnSave to be clicked
$(document).on('click', '.btnSave', function (event) {

    // Here I get the action value in the form tag, split it in chunks and 
    // get the last element in the array, assigned it to the isAdd variable
    var isAdd = $('#customerAddressForm').prop("action").split("/").pop();

    // If the variable value is the same as "Shipping", it means that it's 
    // the edit button that was clicked
    if (isAdd == "Shipping") {

        // I add the following rules to the input with id "inputAddressName"
        $('input[id="inputAddressName"]').rules("add", {
            required: true,
            noSpace: true,

            // Here I do the Ajax call, the value in the customerAddressId 
            // is appended to the url. Example: 
            // https://localhost:8443/mysite/useraccount/isExistingAddressName?addressName=Bill1&customerAddressId=1232. 
            // This get a true/false flag from the server

            remote: {
                url: "https://localhost:8443/mysite/usersite/addresses/isExistingAddressName",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: {
                    customerAddressId: function () {
                        return $("#customerAddressForm").prop("action").split("/").pop();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    // If the variable value is not the same as "Shipping", it means that 
    // it's the add button that was clicked
    } else {
        $('input[id="inputAddressName"]').rules("add", {
            required: true,
            noSpace: true,

            // Here I do the Ajax call for the add, a hardcoded value (-10) 
            //for the customerAddressId is appended to the url. Example: 
            // https://localhost:8443/mysite/useraccount/isExistingAddressName?addressName=Bill1&customerAddressId=-10. 
            //This get a true/false flag from the server.
            remote: {
                url: "https://localhost:8443/mysite/usersite/addresses/isExistingAddressName",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: {
                    customerAddressId: function () {
                        return $("-10");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    $('#customerAddressForm').validate({

        ignore: 'input[type=hidden], .select2-input, .select2-focusser',
        rules: {
            "address.addressLine1": {
                required: true
            },
            "address.addressLine2": {
                number: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "addressName": {
                required: "Please enter an address name",
                remote: "Address name already taken. Please enter another one"
            },
                "address.addressLine1": {
                required: "Please enter your street address"
            },
                "address.addressLine2": {
                number: "Please enter only numbers"
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-item').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-item').removeClass('has-error');
        },
        errorElement: 'small',
        errorClass: 'help-block',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    });
});
```

Is this the right way to pass the url in the remote option depending on a if/else statement? It does not work and I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined.

Comment: *"Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it?"* ~ No.  You have to tell us what's wrong with it.  What is it doing?  What is it failing to do?  What errors are you getting in the console?  You'll also need to show the server-side script, `isExistingAddressName`.

Comment: Please refer to the `remote` documentation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method

Comment: I will reformulate my question I think: is there a way to pass the url in the remote option depending on a if/else statement? For example: if the user clicked edit, then the url should be url-edit. If the user clicked the add button the url should be url-add. I will comment my code to give more hints.By the way, in the console I only get "Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code...

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnSave', function (event) {
    ....
    if (isAdd == "Shipping") {
        $('input[id="inputAddressName"]').rules("add", {
            ....
        });
    } else {
        $('input[id="inputAddressName"]').rules("add", {
            ....
        });
    }

    $('#customerAddressForm').validate(....);  // <-initializes plugin

});
```

> I only get "Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined"

You have some fatal errors in your code...

1. You attempt to use the `.rules()` method *before* you've initialized the plugin on your form; and this is likely the source of your error message.  The `.validate()` method is only used for the *initialization* of the plugin.
2. Since the `.validate()` method is for the initialization of the plugin on your form, and only gets called ***once*** (in DOM ready event), you would **never** put it inside of a `click` handler.

Do this instead...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#customerAddressForm').validate(....); // <-initializes plugin

    $(document).on('click', '.btnSave', function (event) {
        ....
        if (isAdd == "Shipping") {
            $('input[id="inputAddressName"]').rules("add", {
                ....
            });
        } else {
            $('input[id="inputAddressName"]').rules("add", {
                ....
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not work. There's something wrong with my code. I also tried this: `data: {customerAddressId : function() {
var isAdd = $('#customerAddressForm').prop("action").split("/").pop();
if (isAdd == "Shipping") {return $("#customerAddressForm").prop("action").split("/").pop();
} else {
return $("-10");
}
}
}`,but I get this "=%5Bobject+Object%5D" appended to the url.

Comment: @Adorablepolak, that's not coming from anything I've posted.  The jQuery Validate plugin cannot cause anything to get appended to the URL.  **I simply recommended that you properly initialize the plugin by removing the `.validate()` method from the `click` handler.**

Comment: Could you please see the jsbin I created: [http://jsbin.com/zoruroqaki/1/edit?html,js,console,output]. I did what you suggested but when it creates the url I don't get the value I pass to it,but customerAddressId=%5Bobject+Object%5D. I had to review it in a browser as the ajax request does not work in jsbin. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: @Adorablepolak, I have no idea what you're trying to show me in that jsBin, but I definitely think you misunderstand how to use jQuery selectors... `$("-10")` and `$("fdgdfgfdgf")` are meaningless gibberish.   That's why you have `object Object` being appended to your `GET` query string.  See:  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Even if your jQuery selector actually selected something, it would still just be a jQuery object.  You'd need to send the ***value*** of that object, not the entire object.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky. I thought the way to add a hardcoded string to data was like in the example I found on the website. I made a test and I only had to do this: data: {customerAddressId: -10}.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73271/discussion-between-adorablepolak-and-sparky).

Comment: @Adorablepolak, the example on the website uses a jQuery selector to get a specific element and then uses `.val()` to get its value.  That is **very** different than what you tried.

Comment: @Adorablepolak, are you still getting the `Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined` error message?

Comment: in my jsbin, the if/else statement is working fine, the script is entering to the right statement. The issue now is that the variable isAdd is not converted into a string in this line `data: {customerAddressId: isAdd}`. Is this the correct way to add a variable to it?

Comment: @Adorablepolak, You seem to be blindly guessing with no real understanding about any of this.  No, that is not correct.  `data: {customerAddressId: function() { return isAdd; }}` Are you still getting the `Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined` error message?  If not, then I've already answered your OP.

Comment: I think t's related to another issue. With your suggestion and in a form that has not been ajaxed, it does work fine. But my form is in a modal whose fields are ajaxed from a second page. In that scenario, it fails. I created another post for that separate issue. Thanks again.